# Cannot install redis server

Tags: apt, redis

Tried to install redis-server using Kubuntu 16.04 64 bit version using:

```
sudo apt install redis-server
```

But receive this message while installing:

```
Setting up redis-server (2:3.0.7-1~dotdeb+6.1) ...
Job for redis-server.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redis-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Tried to run "journalctl -xe" and found this:

```
redis-server.service: PID file /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post: No such file or directory
```

Any idea to fix this issue?

*** Update ***

"df -h" result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  9,6M  780M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       909G   24G  840G   3% /
tmpfs           3,9G  175M  3,7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  3,6M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           789M     0  789M   0% /run/user/118
tmpfs           789M   12K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
```

"df -h /var/run" result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           789M  9,6M  780M   2% /run
```

Comment: Please add to the question the output of `df -h` and `df -h /var/run`

Comment: Hi Rui, I updated it on my question

Comment: I see it is not lack of space of the /run partition...please add also the output of  `ls -lah /run`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I end up removing redis which installed from apt-get and install the latest stable version from redis website manually. It works fine now...
And I use this guide: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 7):

You should probably alter the redis.conf file to force it to use IPv4 if it supports that mode only and then maybe you could run it without IPv6.

```
nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Simply remove the `::1` IPv6 loopback address from the bind config option:

```
- bind 127.0.0.1 ::1
+ bind 127.0.0.1
```

Now redis will not try to use the IPv6 network.

Try to install again

```
apt install redis-server
```

Test the Redis Instance Functionality
To test that your service is functioning correctly, connect to the Redis server with the command-line client:

```
redis-cli
```

In the prompt that follows, test connectivity by typing:

ping
You should see:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379> ping
```

Output

```
PONG
```

Check that you can set keys by typing:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379> set test "It's working!"
```

Output

```
OK
```

Now, retrieve the value by typing:

```
$ 127.0.0.1:6379> get test
```

You should be able to retrieve the value we stored:

Output

$ 127.0.0.1:6379> "It's working!"

Exit the Redis prompt to get back to the shell:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

As a final test, let's restart the Redis instance:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart redis
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ipv6 issue!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that certain files have the immutable attribute set;
e.g.,

```
---- i --------- e ---- /bin/su
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/bin/passwd
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/bin/chattr
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/adduser
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/useradd
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/userdel
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/usermod
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/groupadd
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/groupdel
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/groupmod
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/sbin/visudo
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/bin/apt-get
---- i --------- e ---- /usr/bin/dpkg
---- i --------- e ---- /etc/passwd
---- i --------- e ---- /etc/shadow
---- i --------- e ---- /etc/group
---- i --------- e ---- /etc/hostname
```

You can check it by doing
`lsattr /usr/bin/passwd`.

You must run `chattr -i FILES`;
for example, `chattr -i /usr/sbin/adduser`.

After modifying the attribute, try to reinstall redis-server.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was related to the port not being open. So I had to do: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest stable version of Redis from the Snapcraft marketplace:

sudo snap install redis